# Socket io client reconnect handler

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, client

I need to implement a reconnect handler which first request a token over ajax from another server which is used as authentication on the websocket server.

Step 1: connect to `http://test.com/{my_temp_token}`
Step 2: on disconnect get new token
Step 3: connect to `http://test.com/{my_new_temp_token}`

Does socket.io automatically reconnect on disconnect? When yes how to implement an own reconnect handler, when no best way to handle an auto reconnect with an ajax loaded authentication token.

Comment: Why is there a disconnect?

Comment: because somebody did stumble over the RJ45 cable. Its the internet there could be thousand possibilities for a disconnect.

Comment: I meant is there a deliberate disconnect. So, if you mean does socket io reconnect if there is a disruption I think the answer is yes but you might want to test it by connecting to your server and unplugging then plugging in the rj45 cable.

Comment: the question is not why it disconnect it is how to have a custom reconnect handler because he will not be able to reconnect with an expired token.

Comment: Ok, I just happen to have uploaded a website yesterday that uses websockets (primus). I did the unplug test and the reconnect was automatic. You can check yourself at http://calitek.com.

Comment: Yeah it reconnect but my websocket server dont allow it as I did describe in my question I need a custom reconnect handler. Before reconnect my client need to request a new TOKEN from another server to authenticate at the websocket server.

Answer (score 0):

Socket io has a list of event listeners that it supports out of the box. If you want to do something custom on reconnect then you would just do...

```
this.socket.on('reconnect', e => {
  // Socket has successfully reconnected
  console.log(`It took ${e} tries to reconnect`);

  // Do something custom like requesting a new token here...
});
```

Hope that helps!